# How to update new properties on many objects returned by an Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I am getting back a large array of objects (categories) from my API. There are anywhere from 50 - 200 categories being returned from the API at once. 
i am creating a source observable that filters all categories into 2 sub-categories and returns them as separate properties under a single object.

```
public allCategories$: Observable<any> = this.categoryService.getAllCategories()
  .pipe(
    map((allCategories: CategoryModel[]) => {
      const red = allCategories.filter((cat) => cat.color === 'red');
      const blue = allCategories.filter((cat) => cat.color === 'blue');
      const allCats = { red, blue };
      return allCats;
    }),
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount()
  )
```

I then use the async pipe to subscribe in angular and then loop over each red/blue stream using separate ngFors.

in my markup, each category has a checkbox associated to it. 
A user can then search through all categories and check the respective checkbox to true, then the user can submit these categories to be routed with params to be handled elsewhere.

The issues i am facing are:

- These user actions are available in two places on the same page: a modal, a typeahead.
- Both components need to be able to read and write to the source observable without updating the database and essentially keeping state for these two components temporarily
- I am having trouble understanding how to update the objects being pushed down after the subscription has started, as it doesnt seem too performant to next 50-200+ objects to a Subject whenever a checkbox is updated

I've looked into some more involved rxjs patterns but they seemed a bit overkill for the already-bloated angular app im working on. 
What would be a good and lean architecture for something like this?

Comment: When a component 'writes' to the source, do the changes have to be seen in the other component as well ? Or it's enough to just _mark_ that a change occurred ?

Comment: the changes are to be seen in both components until the route is changed @AndreiGătej

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for your question you don't need `rxjs` because all the data can be stored in the one component despite it uses several ways inside of how to select the data.

You can simply add a property to store ids of selected categories to the component and it shouldn't be tied with categories data stream and rxjs.

```js
class MyComponent {
  public allCategories$: Observable<any> = this.categoryService.getAllCategories().pipe(
    map((allCategories: CategoryModel[]) => {
      const red = allCategories.filter((cat) => cat.color === 'red');
      const blue = allCategories.filter((cat) => cat.color === 'blue');
      const allCats = { red, blue };
      return allCats;
    }),
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount()
  );

  // here we will store selected ids
  public selectedCategories: Array<string> = []; // array of ids.

  // our callback to handle selection
  public toggleCategory(id: string) {
    if (this.selectedCategories.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      this.selectedCategories = [
        ...this.selectedCategories,
        id,
      ];
    } else {
      this.selectedCategories = this.selectedCategories.filter(v => v !== id);
    }
  }

  // our callback how to save selection
  public submit() {
    this.categoryService.send(this.selectedCategories); // doing something.
  }
}
```

and then in the template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="allCategories$ | async as categories">
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories.red">
    <!-- to manage selection we don't need rxjs -->
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleCategory(category.id)" [checked]="selectedCategories.indexOf(category.id) !== -1"> {{ category.name }}<br>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let category of categories.blue">
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleCategory(category.id)" [checked]="selectedCategories.indexOf(category.id) !== -1"> {{ category.name }}<br>
  </div>

  <button (click)="submit()">Save chosen categories</button>
</ng-container>
```

If you want to share selection between several components then you can create separate service endpoints how to toggle selection and how to fetch it, in this case it might be useful to use `combineLatest([this.allCategories$, this.selectedIds$])`.